# Optional Parameter Python?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I need to create a program called extractGenes.py

The command line parameters need to take 2 OR 3 parameters:

1. `-s` is an optional parameter, or switch, indicating that the user wwants the spliced gene sequence(introns removed). The user does not have to provide this (meaning he wants the entire gene sequence), but it he does provide it then it must be the first parameter
2. input file (with the genes)
3. output file (where the program will create to store the fasta file

The file contains lines like this:

```
NM_001003443 chr11 + 5925152 592608098 2 5925152,5925652, 5925404,5926898,
```

However, I am not sure how to include the `-s` optional parameter into the starting function.

So I started with:

```
getGenes(-s, input, output):
fp = open(input, 'r')
wp = open(output, "w")
```

but am unsure as to how to include the `-s`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This case is simple enough to use [*sys.argv*](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.argv) directly:

```
import sys

spliced = False
if '-s' in sys.argv:
    spliced = True
    sys.argv.remove('-s')
infile, outfile = sys.argv[1:]
```

Alternatively, you can also use the more powerful tools like [*argparse*](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) and [*optparse*](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#module-optparse) to generate a command-line parser:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Tool for extracting genes')
parser.add_argument('infile', help='source file with the genes')
parser.add_argument('outfile', help='outfile file in a FASTA format')
parser.add_argument('-s', '--spliced', action='store_true', help='remove introns')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = parser.parse_args('-s myin myout'.split())
    print vars(result)
```

Comment: @RaymondHettinger, very nice, I've not used argparse before. By the way, I saw your talk about easy AI at PyCon and it was awesome.

Comment: @zallarak Thanks, I'm glad you enjoyed it :-)

Answer (score 2):

Argparse is a python library that willl take care of optional paremeters for you.  http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse

Comment: I am new to python and unsure how to incorporate argparse into the program. I understand the comment above, but since I need the -s to be the first parameter, I do not understand how to make it conditional...

Comment: @PatrickCampbell - dm answered while I was typing my answer, but my solution uses precisely the library he suggested (which is indeed **the** library to use in such cases...)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
def getGenes(input, output, s=False):
    if s:
        ...
    else:
        ...
```

If you input 2 parameters, s will be False;
getGenes(input, output)

If you call getGenes() with 3 parameters, s will be the 3rd parameter, so in this case calling it with any non False value will yield the else clause.

Comment: The problem here is, for whatever reason, the -s has to be the first parameter

Comment: @PatrickCampbell Why, and why does the argument order on the command line have to reflect the argument order of some function in the program?

Comment: I really don't know why the order matters, I wish I didn't have to do it this way, but I was instructed to...

Comment: @PatrickCampbell - are you sure you were instructed that s has to be the first parameter to the *function* (which is just the internal implementation, the user won't see it), and not just the first parameter on the command-line? Given that you keep referring to it as "-s", which is a command-line argument format only, I'm guessing it may really be the latter. Especially since, as zallarak says, the former makes no sense in python.